# Submitting form data to paypal

Tags: paypal

I need to submit the contents of my form from a form that computes the price of the order to the paypal checkout so that clients don't have to reenter product description and prices.
What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to basic HTML forms you can use [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/), specifically the [cart upload method](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/).

If you're comfortable with web service API's I'd recommend going with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/).

There are other options, but those are what I'd recommend starting with.